# Storage Space, 12TB of data using all 54TB of drive space

Tags: hard-drive, powershell, storage-spaces, windows-10-v2004, storage-pool

Ok, so I have 10 hard drives split into two pools.  Total amount of real data is around 12TB, but it’s using 54TB of space and both Storage Spaces show as RAW and Unhealthy.

I cannot access the data.  Anyone know why Storage Space would suddenly eat almost all available space, say there’s no redundancy, and turn the pools into RAW?

Is there any way to fix it by enumerating the slabs using PowerShell?

BTW, I found this amazing script for PowerShell in Administrator mode here:

[Source: Kreel Bits, S2D Continually Refresh Job and Disk Status](http://kreelbits.blogspot.com/2017/02/s2d-continually-refresh-job-and-disk.html?m=1)

```
function RefreshStorageJobStatus () { while($true) { Get-VirtualDisk | ft; Write-Host "-----------";  Get-StorageJob;Start-Sleep -s 10;Clear-Host; } }
```

Then just put in:

```
RefreshStorageJobStatus
```

I wish Windows had a GUI that showed exactly what is was doing like this!